# Get User Profile Picture Without Credentials, Possible?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, user-profile

Working on an email client.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the profile pic of a user from the email and server URL without their password?

I'm working with Exchange 2013. I tried the HTTP POST option provided. It works like a charm but requires a log in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Exchange Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877053%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).

You can have a specific user account impersonate another user account and access their details without the need for their username and password.

```cs
string impName = @"impy";
string impPassword = @"password";
string impDomain = @"domain";
string impEmail = @"impy@domain.com";

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(impName, impPassword, impDomain);
service.AutodiscoverUrl(impEmail);

service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, @"user@domain.com");
```

More references:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you. I'll work on it and post an update. Stuff is progressing a little slower cause of the holidays.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this..

var userpicUrl = "/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?accountname=" + user.UserName + "&size=M&url=" + user.ProfilePictureURl;